# To make text field read only upon a checkbox being TRUE

Tags: fields

The requirement is to make a Text field (user input) read only when a checkbox field is true(checked)

Please suggest .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a standard page (not Visualforce) you could use a validation rule similar to below:

```
myCheckbox__c=True
&&
ISCHANGED(myTextField__c)
```

An alternative would be to use a workflow to change the record type that has the field read only on the page layout. However this isn't true read only as it is enforced in the UI only - if the user has access to edit the record via the API they will be able to modify the text field.

You could also overwrite the page with a visualforce page but that's very much using a hammer to open a nut, and would accrue technical date with the additional maintenance required.

Comment: Yes it's a standard page . So the closest I can achieve is stopping the user from entering any value by displaying the error message . I guess it's not possible to grey out the field ?

Comment: Try the validation rule then :) Have you done one before?

Comment: Yes did the validation rule only . But was wondering if there is any other way out

Comment: I've added some alternatives but the validation rule approach is normally the easiest to do, depending on your specific situation